# ETL to csv files, split up and then pushed to s3 to be consume by redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, kiba-etl

> Just getting started with Kiba, didn't find anything *obvious*, but I could be just channeling my inner child (who looks for their shoes by staring at the ceiling).

I want to dump a very large table to Amazon Redshift. It seems that the fastest way to do that is to write out a bunch of CSV files to an S3 bucket, then tell Redshift (via the `COPY` command) to pull them in. Magical scaling gremlins will do the rest.

So, I think that I want Kiba to write a CSV file for every 10k rows of data, then push it to s3, then start writing to a new file. At the end, make a post-processing call to `COPY`

So, can I "pipeline" the work or should this be a big, nested Destination class?

i.e.

`source -> transform -> transform ... -> [ csv -> s3 ]{every 10000}; post-process`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thibaut, I did something similar, except that I streamed it out to a Tempfile, I think...

```
require 'csv'

# @param limit [Integer, 1_000] Number of rows per csv file
# @param callback [Proc] Proc taking one argument [CSV/io], that can be used after
#        each csv file is finished
module PacerPro
  class CSVDestination
    def initialize(limit: 1_000, callback: ->(obj) { })
      @limit = limit
      @callback = callback

      @csv = nil
      @row_count = 0
    end

    # @param row [Hash] returned from transforms
    def write(row)
      csv << row.values
      @row_count += 1
      return if row_count < limit

      self.close
    end

    # Called by Kiba when the transform pipeline is finished
    def close
      csv.close

      callback.call(csv)

      tempfile.unlink

      @csv = nil
      @row_count = 0
    end

    private

    attr_reader :limit, :callback
    attr_reader :row_count, :tempfile

    def csv
      @csv ||= begin
        @tempfile = Tempfile.new('csv')
        CSV.open(@tempfile, 'w')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks good - thanks for sharing your solution! Hope you'll have a good experience :-)

Answer (score 1):

Kiba author here. Thanks for trying it out!

Currently, the best way to implement this is to create what I'd call a "buffering destination". (A version of that will likely end up in Kiba Common at some point).

*(Please test thoroughly, I just authored that this morning for you, didn't run it at all, although I've used less generic versions in the past. Also keep in mind that this version uses an in-memory buffer for your 10k rows, so growing the number to something much larger will consume memory. A least memory consuming version could also be created though, which would write rows to file as you get them)*

```ruby
class BufferingDestination
  def initialize(buffer_size:, on_flush:)
    @buffer = []
    @buffer_size
    @on_flush = on_flush
    @batch_index = 0
  end

  def write(row)
    @buffer << row
    flush if @buffer.size >= buffer_size
  end

  def flush
    on_flush.call(batch_index: @batch_index, rows: @buffer)
    @batch_index += 1
    @buffer.clear
  end

  def close
    flush
  end
end
```

This is something you can then use like this, for instance here reusing the [Kiba Common CSV destination](https://github.com/thbar/kiba-common#kibacommondestinationscsv) (although you can write your own too):

```ruby
require 'kiba-common/destinations/csv'

destination BufferingDestination,
  buffer_size: 10_000,
  on_flush: -> { |batch_index, rows|
    filename = File.join("output-#{sprintf("%08d", batch_index)}")
    csv = Kiba::Common::Destinations::CSV.new(
      filename: filename,
      csv_options: { ... },
      headers: %w(my fields here)
    )
    rows.each { |r| csv.write(r) }
    csv.close
  }
```

You could then trigger your `COPY` right in the `on_flush` block after generating the file (if you want the upload to start right away), or in a `post_process` block (but this would only start after all the CSV are ready, which can be a feature to ensure some form of transactional global upload if you prefer).

You could go fancy and start a thread queue to actually handle the upload in parallel if you really need this (but then be careful with zombie threads etc).

Another way is to have "multiple steps" ETL processes, with one script to generate the CSV, and another one picking them for upload, running concurrently (this is something I've explained in my talk at [RubyKaigi 2018](https://speakerdeck.com/thbar/kiba-etl-v2-rubykaigi-2018?slide=37) for instance).

Let me know how things work for you!

Comment: My other though was to use a transform to aggregate a bunch of rows, then return the _filename_ to the next step in the pipeline. I haven't tried that, yet, however.

Comment: It's a great idea yet you cannot do that yet at the transform level! I'm planning to implement a change in Kiba that will allow exactly that, though, because I think it would be great for such scenarios - you can comment on this here https://github.com/thbar/kiba/issues/53 or subscribe to get updates. Thanks for the note!

Comment: @KenMayer a first implementation that will ultimately allow what you mention is available here https://github.com/thbar/kiba/pull/57 (to be considered experimental / unstable at this point, but I still thought I'd mention that to you).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure here exact question. But, I think your solution seems correct overall, but few suggestions though.

1. You may wnat too consider even having more then 10K records per CSV file and `gzip` them while sending to S3.
2. You want to see `menifest` creation containing list of multiple files and then run `copy` command supplying `menifest` file as input.